# ExtJs - How to clear the existing value in editable combobox when user starts typing a new value

Tags: extjs, combobox, type-ahead

I have an editable combobox. There will be an existing value in this combobox which comes by default or the user selects it from the dropdown. Now if the user wants to enter a new value in this combobox, I want the existing value to be cleared on the users first keypress. Now I have to select the existing value manually and delete it and then start typing a new value. Is there a way to handle this so that as soon as a user starts typing a value in the combobox, the old value should be cleared out.

Thanks,

Comment: May I say that what you describe seems unorthodox? The user will see a cursor somewhere and the moment he types something you'll delete it and somehow add again what he wrote? He could press an arrow or do a copy-paste or have some part selected to change the ending only...  I think you'd provide a much better user experience, much more familiar, if you used ExtJS's `emptyText`. You can style it a bit not to be too grey if you want. And when you need the value just do a `getValue() || mydefaultvalue`. You can even read it directly from `initialConfig.emptyText` if you don't want to repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  1. You can do it by using **focus** event listener for combo
> ```

```
 listeners:{
    focus:function( combo, The, eOpts ){
             combo.clearValue();
           }

  }
```

> ```
>  2. You can use **keypress/keyup** event listeners also depending
> ```
>
> on your requirements by enabling key events using **enableKeyEvents :true** for combo.

```
 listeners:{
    keypress:function( combo, e, eOpts ){
             combo.clearValue();
           }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try it and will let you know.